# can't press start on Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I want to run my Android project by using Genymotion plugin

But I can't press start after choosing the available device

[image: genymotion plugin]

Answer (score 0):

- Just **restart the android studio** after install genymotion plugin

> **Still no react go to**

- **File > invalidate caches and restart**..

Happy coding...

Comment: nop even invalidate caches and restart didnt workout :(